# The * in C++ Initialisations

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

What does the * mean when initialising a class?
Normally in AS3 I would do this:

```
MyClass myClass = new MyClass
```

But I have seen this in c++

```
 MyClass *myClass = new MyClass
```

What is the star for? I've seen it used sometimes and not others.

Comment: Look up pointers. Try not to dynamically allocate memory when possible, or at least use a vector/smart pointer.

Comment: This is basic knowledge, see [The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Comment: Why so many downvotes? He couldn't have googled it, you can't google *, he would have needed to already know it's a pointer in order to google it.

Comment: @satuon I didn't downvote but if doesn't even know what a `*` in C++ he should pick up a textbook before asking questions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The asterisk in C++ means many things depending on its place in the program. In this specific instance, it modifies the meaning of `myClass` to be a *pointer* to an instance of `MyClass`, rather than an instance of `MyClass`.

The difference between the two is that the lifetime of an instance ends when it goes out of scope, while an instance that you allocate and reference through a pointer remains valid even after a pointer goes out of scope.

It is valid to have a declaration like this:

```
MyClass myClass; // no "new"
```

In this case, it is not necessary to use `new`, but the instance's life time is tied to the scope of the variable `myClass`.

Comment: So do I need to initialise my class first and then when I refer to it later use *myClass?

Comment: @user1013512 In C++ you have several options, as far as dealing with classes goes. You can use `new` to allocate an instance dynamically; in this case, the asterisk is necessary, and then you use `->` operator instead of a dot `.` to access members of the class. You must also call `delete myClass` when you are done with the object. You can also skip `new` altogether and use the dot `.`, but the object will be deleted as soon as its variable goes out of scope.

Answer (score 2):

An asterisk stand for a `pointer`. A pointer is a memory adress. When you write `MyClass *myClass`, you create a pointer to the beginning of the bits range where your new MyClass is created.

Creating an object with `new`, you become responsible of it life cycle. YOU will need to delete it when you dont need them anymore, whereas creating `MyClass myClass;` will be destroy when exiting the scope where you create it. You still can access myClass memory adress even when written this way, using `&` operator.

If you need more explaination, try to get one of [those books](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: it is more commonly called "asterisk" instead of "star".

Answer (score 2):

It's called a pointer. If you're using a C++11 compatible compiler, you can do the following:

`auto myClass = std::make_shared<MyClass>();`

If you were using a "raw" pointer, you would need to manually delete it when you are finished with the memory, with the `shared_ptr`, this isn't necessary.